# Replace missing value with previous value

Tags: r, zoo

```
Event,Time,Bid,Offer
Quote,0.458338,9.77,9.78
Order,0.458338,NA,NA
Order,0.458338,NA,NA
Order,0.458338,NA,NA
Quote,0.458363,9.78,9.79
Order,0.458364,NA,NA
```

I have a Data frame like this
I want to write a efficient code to fill up the NA with previous Quote bid and ask,  Time is sorted, and only Quote contains bid and ask field (preferably vectorization)

so it becomes

```
Event,Time,Bid,Offer
Quote,0.458338,9.77,9.78
Order,0.458338,9.77,9.78
Order,0.458338,9.77,9.78
Order,0.458338,9.77,9.78
Quote,0.458363,9.78,9.79
Order,0.458364,9.78,9.79
```

thanks

Answer (score 21):

The `na.locf()` function in the **zoo** package is your friend here. The `locf` stands for "last one carried forward". With your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Event,Time,Bid,Offer
Quote,0.458338,9.77,9.78
Order,0.458338,NA,NA
Order,0.458338,NA,NA
Order,0.458338,NA,NA
Quote,0.458363,9.78,9.79
Order,0.458364,NA,NA
", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

require(zoo)

dat2 <- transform(dat, Bid = na.locf(Bid), Offer = na.locf(Offer))
```

Produces.

```
> dat2
  Event     Time  Bid Offer
1 Quote 0.458338 9.77  9.78
2 Order 0.458338 9.77  9.78
3 Order 0.458338 9.77  9.78
4 Order 0.458338 9.77  9.78
5 Quote 0.458363 9.78  9.79
6 Order 0.458364 9.78  9.79
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# Last Observation Move Forward
na.lomf <- function(object, na.rm = F) {
    na.lomf.0 <- function(object) {
        idx <- which(!is.na(object))
        if (is.na(object[1])) idx <- c(1, idx)
        rep.int(object[idx], diff(c(idx, length(object) + 1)))
    }    
    dimLen <- length(dim(object))
    object <- if (dimLen == 0) na.lomf.0(object) else apply(object, dimLen, na.lomf.0)
    if (na.rm) na.trim(object, sides = "left", is.na = "all") else object
}
```