# How to spread same valuables with conditions R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
# Dataset name : df 
    Int.Index  Int.Line Name  Index  Index.Line  Amount
    340         1       John  440      1          700
    ""          2       John  440      2          100
    ""          3       John  400      3           50
    450         1       May   500      1         2401
    5694        1       Paul  6023     1         1312
    ""          2       Paul  6023     2         7244
```

Desired Output

```
# Desired ouput 
    Int.Index  Int.Line Name  Index  Index.Line  Amount
    340         1       John  440      1          700
    340         2       John  440      2          100
    340         3       John  400      3           50
    450         1       May   500      1         2401
    5694        1       Paul  6023     1         1312
    5694        2       Paul  6023     2         7244
```

I am a beginner know what `group_by` function doing but cannot achieve the
copy value part of it .

Comment: Can you edit your question so it's easy for us to cut and paste and get your df into our R sessions to work on this? Thanks.

Comment: Replace [Blank Cells to “NA”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172111/change-the-blank-cells-to-na) and then [use na.locf to replace with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655286/replace-missing-value-with-previous-value).

Comment: df <- read.table(
  header = T, text = 'Int.Index  Int.Line Name  Index  Index.Line  Amount
    340         1       John  440      1          700
    ""          2       John  440      2          100
    ""          3       John  400      3           50
    450         1       May   500      1         2401
    5694        1       Paul  6023     1         1312
    ""          2       Paul  6023     2         7244 ')       Thankyou mysteRious , here is the data with script