# Handling missing values in time series replacing with previous values

Tags: r, time-series

I am dealing with time series data where I need to have continuous time stamps but few of the data timestamp points has been missed while capturing like as below,

`DF`

```
ID Time_Stamp             A           B                 C
1  02/02/2018 07:45:00   123          567               434     
2   02/02/2018 07:45:01    
.....                  ...

5   02/02/2018 07:46:00   
6   02/02/2018 07:46:10    112          2323            2323
```

As shown in the sample df above, time stamps is continuous till row 5 but missed capturing data of 10 seconds between 5th and 6th row. My data frame is about 60000 rows and identifying missing values manually is tedious. Hence I was looking for automating the procedure of handling missing values using R

My result data frame should be as shown below,

```
ID Time_Stamp                     A          B          C
1  02/02/2018 07:45:00           123         567        434     
2   02/02/2018 07:45:01    
.....                  ...

5   02/02/2018 07:46:00         123         567         434
5.1  02/02/2018 07:46:01        123         567         434 
5.2  02/02/2018 07:46:02        123         567         434  
5.3  02/02/2018 07:46:03        123         567         434  
5.4  02/02/2018 07:46:04        123         567         434 
5.5  02/02/2018 07:46:05        123         567         434 
5.6  02/02/2018 07:46:06        123         567         434 
5.7  02/02/2018 07:46:07        123         567         434 
5.8  02/02/2018 07:46:08        123         567         434 
5.9  02/02/2018 07:46:09        123         567         434 
6   02/02/2018 07:46:10         112         2323        2323
6.1 02/02/2018 07:46:11         112         2323        2323
```

i.e my last row before missing value . It is came values that for row number 5 and should fill same till next value is available.

I tried following code to add `0` as values to it. But could not do for previous row values of missing value

```
df1<- df %>%
  complete(Timestamp = seq(min(Timestamp), max(Timestamp), by = "sec")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(A:C), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0 )) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number())
```

I got output as follows:

```
ID Time_Stamp                     A        B        C
1  02/02/2018 07:45:00           123      567      434     
2   02/02/2018 07:45:01    
.....                  ...

5   02/02/2018 07:46:00         123       567      434
5.1  02/02/2018 07:46:01        0         0         0 
5.2  02/02/2018 07:46:02        0         0         0  
5.3  02/02/2018 07:46:03        0         0         0  
5.4  02/02/2018 07:46:04        0         0         0 
5.5  02/02/2018 07:46:05        0         0         0 
5.6  02/02/2018 07:46:06        0         0         0 
5.7  02/02/2018 07:46:07        0         0         0 
5.8  02/02/2018 07:46:08        0         0         0 
5.9  02/02/2018 07:46:09        0         0         0 
6   02/02/2018 07:46:10         112       2323      2323
6.1 02/02/2018 07:46:11         0         0         0
```

I want previous row to be replaced with 0 value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear. Can you show what would be your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah , Hi i want the previous row data value i.e `Row number 5 for all the missing values between 5 and 6`, And `row number 6 for value missing between 6 and 7`.Its like keeping previous value same for missing values i.e` i = i-1` value for all the missing rows data.

Comment: @RonakShah . I mean `0` value should be replace with 5th row values.

Comment: Do you need `df %>%
  complete(Time_Stamp = seq(min(Time_Stamp), max(Time_Stamp), by = "sec")) %>%
  fill(A, B, C)
` ?

Comment: @RonakShah last value of `A,B,C`

Comment: After completing the Time_Stamp the problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655286/replace-missing-value-with-previous-value

Comment: @RahulK what do you mean by last value A, B, C? Last non-NA value of `A`, `B` and `C` respectively right? Can you check the output given by `df %>% complete(Time_Stamp = seq(min(Time_Stamp), max(Time_Stamp), by = "sec")) %>% fill(A, B, C) ` what does it give?

Comment: @RonakShah `Error: df1_p[, 2:11] must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list` I have 11 variables in my original `DF`

Comment: Hmmm..not sure. Try this `df %>%
  complete(Time_Stamp = seq(min(Time_Stamp), max(Time_Stamp), by = "sec")) %>%
  fill(everything())
`

Comment: @RonakShah This code worked for me perfectly. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works perfectly

```
 df1<- df %>%
      complete(Timestamp = seq(min(Timestamp), max(Timestamp), by = "sec")) %>%
      fill(everything()) %>%
      mutate(ID = row_number())
```

It adds missing data with the previous or last value before the missing data time is started.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the `xtx` Package**
The `xts` package has some functions for dealing with missing values. What you want is called LOCF (short for Last Observation Carried Forward). The `xtx` package has an `na.locf` function for this purpose. Please also note that you will have to convert your data to an xtx object beforehand.

```
my_xts <- xts(df[3:5], order.by=df[2])
newData <- na.locf(my_xts, na.rm = TRUE, fromLast = FALSE, maxgap=Inf)
```

Please note that since an xtx object is built on top of a matrix class, it expects all columns to be of the same type (i.e. in your case, all columns except the timestamp should be numeric. The timestamp goes into the index of xtx object). Also, note that Time_Stamp should be of type should be date/time.

**More generally**
Generally, for dealing with missing values, you can use the `na.interp()` function from the `forecast` package. `na.interp()` replaces missing values with interpolated values. And it can also interpolate seasonal data.
As quoted from its documentation;

> By default, uses linear interpolation for non-seasonal series. For seasonal series, a robust STL decomposition is first computed. Then a linear interpolation is applied to the seasonally adjusted data, and the seasonal component is added back.

`na.interp()` can't deal with dataframes directly. You will have to convert your data into a time series object (ts or msts objects).

```
library(forecast)
my_msts <- df['A'] %>% 
 msts() %>%
 na.interp()
```

**Using tidyr**
The `fill` function from `tidyr` package makes this very simple. In that case, there's no need to convert the data to a time series object.
From tidyr documentation:

> **Description:**
>   Fills missing values in selected columns using the previous entry.  This is useful in the commonoutput format where values are not repeated, they’re recorded each time they change.
>   **Usage:**
>   fill(data, ..., .direction = c("down", "up"))